# Does positive topological entropy imply horseshoes?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, entropy, chaos-theory

I am aware that positive topological entropy implies chaos in the sense of Li-Yorke. I want to get an idea of what consequences positive topological entropy has for the the presence (or lack of) chaotic dynamics in the following alternative formulation of "chaotic dynamics", specifically:

If a given invertible dynamical system $\Phi$ on a phase space $M$ has positive topological entropy, does this imply that it has a Smale horseshoe structure in at least a part of the phase space?

By a horseshoe, I mean an invariant (Cantor) set on which $\Phi$ has dynamics which is topologically conjugate to a shift map $\sigma$ on $N$ symbols.

Conversely, does zero topological entropy imply that horseshoes cannot exist?

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is **yes** if $\Phi$ is a $C^{1+\alpha}$ diffeomorphism, due to work of Anatole Katok in the context of smooth ergodic theory, in his beautiful paper *Lyapunov exponents, entropy and periodic orbits for diffeomorphisms*,
>   Inst. Hautes Études Sci. Publ. Math. **51** (1980), 137-173.

To my best knowledge, it is unknown whether this part of smooth ergodic theory goes over to  $C^1$ diffeomorphisms, this would require a very careful inspection of every detail. I would say that it has some possibilities.

> On the other hand, the answer to your last question is obviously positive: horseshoes carry positive topological entropy, due to the topological conjugacy to the full shift.

*PS: By the way: do you really know that your first sentence holds for maps other than maps of the interval? I presume not, but otherwise I would be glad to know.*

Comment: Thanks. Yes indeed, I meant maps on the interval in my first sentence @John B